# R data.table select set of columns for maximum value based on group

Tags: r, data.table, max

I saw multiple posts to meet my requirement, but some how not able to get the needed result.

I have a data.table with multiple columns. Out of all the columns I want to select few columns for their maximum value and summarize them by the group variable.

Below is how my sample data -

```
library("data.table")
set.seed(1200)

ID <- seq(1001,1100)
region <- sample(1:10,100,replace = T)
Q21 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
Q22 <- sample(1:15,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_1 <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_2 <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_3 <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_4 <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)

Q21_PAN <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
Q22_PAN <- sample(1:15,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_1_PAN <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_2_PAN <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_3_PAN <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)
Q24_LOC_4_PAN <- sample(1:8,100,replace = T)

df1 <- as.data.table(data.frame(ID,region,Q21,Q22,Q24_LOC_1,Q24_LOC_2,Q24_LOC_3,Q24_LOC_4,Q21_PAN,Q22_PAN,Q24_LOC_1_PAN,Q24_LOC_2_PAN,Q24_LOC_3_PAN,Q24_LOC_4_PAN))
```

Now for the above data I want to select 4 columns for their maximum value by region. So the result should have the ID variable, region variable and these 4 variables with 10 rows. 1 row for each region. I tried below code but it creates a column as mycol and puts the value of the 4th element of vector mycol

```
mycol <- paste("Q24","LOC",seq(1:4),"PAN",sep = "_")

df2 <- df1[,.(mycol = max(mycol)),by=region]
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong and how I can achieve this.

Comment: @akrun, thank you for noticing. I have edited mycol. However I still do not get the desired result

Comment: It is not clear about the ID variable, because each row have unique IDs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to get `max`, after grouping by 'region' and specifying the 'mycol' in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `max`

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, max), by = region, .SDcols = mycol]
```

If there are 'region' that have only NA values, the `max` will return with a warning as it returns `Inf`.  For example,

```
max(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] -Inf
```

> Warning message: In max(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE) :   no non-missing
>   arguments to max; returning -Inf

To correct this, we could add an `if/else` condition

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_integer_
       else max(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = region, .SDcols = mycol]
```

---

If we also need 'ID' as a `paste`d string

```
df1[, c(list(ID = toString(ID)), lapply(.SD, max)), by = region, .SDcols = mycol]
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for...looking at the result I think ID variable would not be needed....However please if you could suggest on NA and NaN.....I have few NA and NaN in my data and I passed na.rm = T after max but still getting warnings **In max("Q24_LOC_PAN_1", na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf** I believe I can ignore this, but is there a way to take care of these warnings as well?

Comment: @user1412  I think the reason is taht there are cases where you have only `NA` i.e. `max(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] -Inf`

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are variables for few regions which are all NA. Thank you once again for clarifying !!

Comment: Great, this is a very valuable input to correct -Inf. Now it gives me NA instead of -Inf also it was giving error of tyoe double for my data and I changed NA_integer_ to NA_real_ and it gives me proper NA now.  Thank you and +1 for this input